# Numpy not recognized even though it is installed

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

VSCode, Python3.8.4 64-bit, first assignment with Jupyter notebooks. I have installed numpy but when I run `import numpy as np` I receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. I'm very new please be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

Write pip list in anaconda prompt or cmd and search for it if you don t find it then it s a problem of path

Comment: Thank you for responding. I see numpy version 1.19.1 when I run `pip list`. Also, no matter how many times I install IPyKernel I still receive an error saying `IPyKernel not installed into interpreter Python 3.8.4 64-bit`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this worked but I changed my python interpreter in VSCode to 3.8.5 and now I'm all good.